# How to impute NaN values to a default value if strategy fails?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation

## Problem

I am using the [sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) class to impute NaN values using a *mean* strategy over the columns, i.e. axis=0. My problem is that some data which needs to be imputed *only* has NaN values in it's column, e.g. when there is only a single entry.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

data = np.array([[1, 2, np.NaN]])
data = Imputer().fit_transform(data)
```

This gives an output of `array([[1., 2.]])`

Fair enough, obviously the Imputer cannot compute a mean for a set of values which are all NaN. However, instead of removing the value I would like to fall back to a default value, in my case 0.

## Current approach

To solve this problem I first check whether an entire column only contains NaN values, and if so, replace them with my default value 0:

```
# Loop over all columns in data
for column in data.T:
    # Check if all values in column are NaN
    if all(np.isnan(value) for value in column):
        # Fill the column with default value 0
        column.fill(0)
```

## Question

Is there a more elegant way to impute to a default value if an entire axis only contains NaN values?

Comment: can you change `does not have non-NaN values in it's column` to `does have NaN values in it's column`. this will be easy to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a vectorized solution to do what you're doing in a for loop and so should be much faster

```
default = 0
data[:, np.isnan(data).all(axis=0)] = default
```

You can then apply your `Imputer().fit_transform()` method to the new `data`.

---

Example

```
data = np.array([[np.nan, 1, 1], [np.nan]*3, [1, 2, 3]]).T
```

which looks like

```
[[nan nan  1.]
 [ 1. nan  2.]
 [ 1. nan  3.]]
```

Applying our method to remove `nan`s

```
default = 0
data[:, np.isnan(data).all(axis=0)] = default
```

and we get

```
[[nan  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  2.]
 [ 1.  0.  3.]]
```